# Eleventy/njk - collection based on dynamic tag

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

new to eleventy, I'm trying to create a collection index page based on a tag defined in the parent (front matter)

For example, a City:

```
---
name: New York
tags: ['cities']
restaurant_tag: USNYNY
---
```

And a restaurant in NYC:

```
---
name: Awesome Reststaurant
tags: ['USNYNY', 'italian', 'etc']
---
```

How would I create this?  I get no results from the "obvious (to me)" query

`{% for restaurant in collections.restaurant_tag %}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create custom collection, try to filter all items with [addCollection](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#advanced-custom-filtering-and-sorting)